# why this jQuery response with "undefined"?

Tags: jquery, json

This jQuery code response with "undefined" why ??

```
    function YouTube2()
    {
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var txt="";
            var url='https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=GoogleDevelopers&max-results=10&v=2&alt=jsonc';
            $.getJSON(url,function(json) {
                alert("ss");
                $.each(json.data.items, function(index, elem) {
                    alert(json.data.items[index].thumbnail.default);
                });
             });
        });
     }
     YouTube2();
```

Comment: Firebug (the net console) shows what? I am gonna guess `thumbnail` isn't what you think it is -- perhaps it's a string or array. Nope, actually you just used `default` when it sends `sqDefault` (all I did was open the link...). If I had votes left I'd downvote for no apparent research/debugging ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

change default to sqDefault or hqDefault

http://sandbox.phpcode.eu/g/6aea7

```
        alert(json.data.items[index].thumbnail.Default);
```

to

```
        alert(json.data.items[index].thumbnail.sqDefault);
```

or to

```
        alert(json.data.items[index].thumbnail.hqDefault);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `default` in the thumbnail object. There is `sqDefault` and `hqDefault`:

```
"thumbnail":{"sqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/-kepYfCBg6w/default.jpg","hqDefault":"http://i.ytimg.com/vi/-kepYfCBg6w/hqdefault.jpg"}
```

Pick the one you want and use it :)

Comment: same answer as I posted 2 minutes ago

Comment: @genesis lol yes I was answering another question and left this open so it was kind of slow :P

Comment: it's happening for me very often, too :)

Answer (score -2):

You are doing a cross domain request, something that you **can't do** because of the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy)

Comment: That code is broken. It's trying to make a cross-domain request. It doesn't matter if you have a flag or whatever to bypass it on your browser

Comment: access-control-allow-origin:* is allowing your browser to access that json without jsonp

Comment: Is that something firefox only? googling results in (mostly) MDC docs